# XX:NativeMemoryTracking Native memory tracking has been shutdown due to out of native memory

Tags: java, memory-management

i'm trying to get memory usage statistic using `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking` with *summary* and *detail* values.

then call jcmd pid `VM.native_memory summary *(or detail)*`

And always get error **"Native memory tracking has been shutdown due to out of native memory"** 
I have 12Gb RAM i tried ti give java 2GB or 10GB, i tried everything, but can't understand whats wrong.

I use

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `-XX:-AutoShutdownNMT`?

> NMT will shut itself down when it detects low resource conditions, such as when running low on native memory. Sometimes that may be the situation when you would really want the data!

From [here](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=401).

Answer (score 0):

Understandably, the Native Memory Tracker probably uses some native memory itself. I suggest you use another application to track native memory usage of your jvm, or use the tools provided by your OS. On windows you can use `perfmon` and on linux, `ps -p <PID> -o vsz`.

See http://www.techpaste.com/2012/07/steps-debugdiagnose-memory-memory-leaks-jvm/ for more details.

Comment: No, i need extended information about what exactly use memory and how. The question is why **-XX:NativeMemoryTracking** don't work?